# Double series problems

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, power-series

How to calculate$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}{\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(6m\right)^2+\left(6n+1\right)^2}}}.$$Follow [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189199/how-to-calculate-the-infinite-sum-of-this-double-series),we first get $$\sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{{{\left( {6k + 1} \right)}^2} + {l^2}}}}  = \frac{{{l^2}}}{{{l^4} + 1}} - \frac{1}{{{l^2} + 1}} - \frac{\pi }{{12l}}\left( {\frac{{\sinh \frac{{\pi l}}{6}}}{{\cosh \frac{{\pi l}}{6} + \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}}} + \frac{{\sinh \frac{{\pi l}}{6}}}{{ - \cosh \frac{{\pi l}}{6} + \frac{{\sqrt 3 }}{2}}}} \right).$$But it seems difficult to continue!

Comment: Why are people voting to close?

Comment: I downvoted because I think that the OP should explain the context. How did you come to that summation? Why are there those 6's and not a general parameter $a$? What do you mean by "calculate"?

Comment: @Fry, OP would have to be a mindreader to understand that that's what you found wrong with the question. Can I encourage you (and others) to help posters by leaving a comment when you downvote? (or even instead of making that downvote?)

Answer (score 6):

The paper [Two-dimensional series evaluations via the elliptic
functions of Ramanujan and Jacobi](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/berndtlambrogers.pdf) deals exactly with double sums of this kind and shows how to evaluate them in terms of elliptic functions.

The book [Lattice sums then and now](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9781107039902) gives alternative methods to calculate lattice sums.

Comment: Thank you, Lattice sums are series about $(-1)^{m+n}$, my question is about $(-1)^n$,I hope Lattice sums' method can work well.